# How to automatically configure HTTP referrers in Google API console for web hosting for firebase preview channel hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, http-referer, google-api-console

Whenever I deploy a website in Firebase hosting, first I run them in firebase preview channel with the preview channel name as *alpha*
The command for deploying to preview channel is

`firebase hosting:channel:deploy alpha`

The issue with this is that after one expiration of channel when I create new channel it creates a new URL in the form of

> https://<project-id>--alpha-<random-hash>.web.app

where *random-hash* is different every time.
Since my website has Google sign-in and my project has HTTP referrer set to the web API key for security reasons, with the new preview URL created every time my Google sign stops working with the error:

> {"error":{"code":403,"message":"Requests from referer https://<project-id>--alpha-<random-hash>.web.app/ are blocked.","errors":[{"message":"Requests from referer https://<project-id>--alpha-<random-hash>.web.app/ are blocked.","domain":"global","reason":"forbidden"}],"status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}

Is there a general way to add HTTP referrer in Google API console for website pattern like below

> https://<project-id>--alpha-*.web.app

Right now adding this gives an error in the Google API console

Comment: I have the same problem. You can add this domain `<project-id>--alpha-*.web.app` (without the https://) in the console and it doesn't report any errors, but it doesn't work. Were you able to get it to work?

Comment: The way I was able to get it to work was with this `*.web.app/*`. But it unfortunately widens the domain whitelist more than I want.

Comment: @JohnnyOshika Widening the allowed domain defeats the purpose of setting this whitelisting

Comment: We've been coming up against this issue as well. One potential solution (that we aren't pursuing yet but may in the future) would be to add some kind of `postDeploy` script that calls the Google Cloud [API Keys API](https://cloud.google.com/api-keys/docs/add-restrictions-api-keys) to add the preview channel URL as a referrer. You would need to eventually clean these up, but it could be done.